# Timestamp.from not heeding timezone from Instant

Tags: java, timestamp, java-time, zoneddatetime, java.time.instant

When I try to convert a `ZonedDateTime` to a `Timestamp` everything is fine until I call `Timestamp.from()` in the following code:

```
ZonedDateTime currentTimeUTC = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
currentTimeUTC = currentTimeUTC.minusSeconds(currentTimeUTC.getSecond());
currentTimeUTC = currentTimeUTC.minusNanos(currentTimeUTC.getNano());
return Timestamp.from(currentTimeUTC.toInstant());

ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC); -> 2018-04-26T12:31Z
currentTimeUTC.toInstant() -> 2018-04-26T12:31:00Z
Timestamp.from(currentTimeUTC.toInstant()) -> 2018-04-26 14:31:00.0 
// (with Timezone of Europe/Berlin, which is currently +2)
```

Why is `Timestamp.from()` not heeding the timezone set in the instant?

Comment: Are you sure you need a `Timestamp`? Current JDBC drivers and JPA implementations are happy to let you insert an `Instant` or a `LocalDateTime`  into your database. This way you can avoid the outdated `Timestamp` class completely. In case you do: Your `Timestamp` holds the correct and expected point in time. It is only its `toString` method using your default time zone when it produces the string for display (your debugger calls `toString` assuming this will give it the proper string to display to you).

Comment: Nope, I don't need it. I did refactor it with Instant yesterday!  Thanks for your comment and help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Instant` class doesn't have a timezone, it just has the values of seconds and nanoseconds since unix epoch. A `Timestamp` also represents that (a count from epoch).

> why is the debugger displaying this with a Z behind it?

The problem is in the `toString` methods:

`Instant.toString()` converts the seconds and nanoseconds values to the corresponding date/time in UTC - hence the "Z" in the end - and I believe it was made like that for convenience (to make the API more "developer-friendly").

[The javadoc for `toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toString--) says:

> A string representation of this instant using ISO-8601 representation.
>   The format used is the same as `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT`.

And if we take a look at [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT):

> The ISO instant formatter that formats or parses an instant in UTC, such as '2011-12-03T10:15:30Z'

As debuggers usually uses the `toString` method to display variables values, that explains why you see the `Instant` with "Z" in the end, instead of the seconds/nanoseconds values.

On the other hand, `Timestamp.toString` uses the JVM default timezone to convert the seconds/nanos values to a date/time string.

But the values of both `Instant` and `Timestamp` are the same. You can check that by calling the methods `Instant.toEpochMilli` and `Timestamp.getTime`, both will return the same value.

---

Note: instead of calling `minusSeconds` and `minusNanos`, you could use the `truncatedTo` method:

```
ZonedDateTime currentTimeUTC = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
currentTimeUTC = currentTimeUTC.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
```

This will set all fields smaller than `ChronoUnit.MINUTES` (in this case, the seconds and nanoseconds) to zero.

You could also use `withSecond(0)` and `withNano(0)`, but in this case, I think `truncatedTo` is better and more straight to the point.

---

Note2: the java.time API's creator also made a backport for Java 6 and 7, and in the project's github issues [you can see a comment](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threeten/issues/271#issuecomment-14204085) about the behaviour of `Instant.toString`. The relevant part to this question:

> If we were really hard line, the toString of an Instant would simply be the number of seconds from 1970-01-01Z. We chose not to do that, and **output a more friendly toString to aid developers**

That reinforces my view that the `toString` method was designed like this for convenience and ease to use.

Comment: Thanks for making things clear! Really a great answer with useful insights :)

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

- You are being confused by the unfortunate behavior of `Timestamp::toString` to apply the JVM’s current default time zone to the objects internal UTC value.
- ➡ Use [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html), never `Timestamp`.
- A String such as `2018-04-26T12:31Z` is in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, with the `Z` being short for `Zulu` and meaning [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

Your entire block of code can be replaced with:

```
Instant.now()
```

…such as:

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , Instant.now() ) ;
```

## Details

The [Answer by wowxts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50047516/642706) is correct. `Instant` is always in UTC, as is `Timestamp`, yet `Timestamp::toString` applies a time zone. This behavior is one of many poor design choices in those troubled legacy classes.

I'll add some other thoughts.

## Use `Instant` for UTC

> ZonedDateTime currentTimeUTC = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);

While technically correct, this line is semantically wrong. If you want to represent a moment in UTC, use `Instant` class. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment in UTC.
```

## Avoid legacy `Timestamp` class

> Timestamp.from(currentTimeUTC.toInstant());

While technically correct, using my suggest above, that would be:

```
Timestamp.from( instant ); // Convert from modern *java.time* class to troublesome legacy date-time class using new method added to the old class.
```

Nothing is lost going between `Instant` and `Timestamp`, as both represent a moment in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds. However…

No need to be using `java.sql.Timestamp` at all! That class is part of the troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy. They were supplanted entirely by the *java.time* classes defined by JSR 310. `Timestamp` is replaced by `Instant`.

## JDBC 4.2

As of JDBC 4.2 and later, you can directly exchange *java.time* objects with your database.

Insert/Update.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instant ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Great answer and great insight as well! Thanks for that, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Instant does not hold the Timezone information. It only holds the seconds and nanos.
To when you convert your ZonedDateTime into an Instant the information is lost.
When converting into Timestamp then the Timestamp will hold the default Timezone, which is, in your case, Europe/Berlin.

Comment: holy moly, why is the debugger displaying this with a Z behind it? That's acutally indicating UTC. But yeah, you're right, the object is only holding the seconds and nanos.

Comment: Not quite a complete answer. The "seconds and nanos" being held represent a count from the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 in UTC. So the context and meaning of a `Instant` is UTC, always UTC. So converting from `ZonedDateTime` to `Instant` does not *lose* information, it *adjusts* the information from some other time zone to UTC.